Getting Error: DiscoveryService: mainchannel error: access denied
I am trying to submit a transaction using the contract object of the which is obtained after connecting to the fabric network through the gateway.
Gateway is being established successfully but when trying to use gateway.getNetwork() method gives out this error:
2024-04-24T14:55:04.414Z - error: [DiscoveryResultsProcessor]: parseDiscoveryResults[mainchannel] - Channel:mainchannel received discovery error:access denied

 /home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryResultsProcessor.js:31

throw Error(`DiscoveryService: ${this.service.name} error: ${result.error.content}`);

                      ^

Error: DiscoveryService: mainchannel error: access denied
at DiscoveryResultsProcessor.parseDiscoveryResults (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryResultsProcessor.js:31:11)
at DiscoveryService.send (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-common/lib/DiscoveryService.js:341:35)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async NetworkImpl._initializeInternalChannel (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:303:13)
at async NetworkImpl._initialize (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/network.js:253:9)
at async Gateway.getNetwork (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/gateway.js:355:9)
at async connection (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:133:21)
at async main (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:168:5)

Below is the function which is giving out the error:
const connection = async (ccp, wallet, userName) => {
    const gateway = new Gateway()
    await gateway.connect(ccp, {
        wallet,
        identity: userName,
        discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } // using asLocalhost as this gateway is using a fabric network deployed locally
    });

    const network = await gateway.getNetwork(process.env.CHANNEL);
    console.log(network)

    // Get the contract from the network.
    // const contract = network.getContract(process.env.CONTRACT);
    // console.log(contract)

    // const result = await contract.submitTransaction('CreateEvidence', "xyxyx", userName, "100", "Hacking", "xss.png", "png", "zzzzz")
    // console.log(result)
}

Tried chainging the discovery to false and the gateway.getNetwork() and network.getContract() worked but produced below error at contract.submitTransaction()

2024-04-24T15:05:50.716Z - error: [Transaction]: Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    at newEndorsementError (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:77:12)
    at getResponsePayload (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:45:23)
    at Transaction.submit (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:258:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async connection (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:140:20)
    at async main (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:168:5)
node:internal/process/promises:289
            triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);

            ^

Error: No valid responses from any peers. Errors:
    at newEndorsementError (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:77:12)
    at getResponsePayload (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:45:23)
    at Transaction.submit (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/node_modules/fabric-network/lib/transaction.js:258:28)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async connection (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:140:20)
    at async main (/home/kshitij/Desktop/api/fabric-test-task/server.js:168:5) {
  responses: [],
  errors: []
}

the connection-profile.json
{
    "name": "EvidenceVault-Forensic",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Forensic",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Police": {
            "mspid": "ForensicMSP",
            "peers": [
                "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
                "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:9051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nuV1vWo+zP/g8cWor7fEI8rPjz4SLw/3Rpw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "FD100.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            }
        },
        "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:10051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nuV1vWo+zP/g8cWor7fEI8rPjz4SLw/3Rpw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "FD101.forensic.evidence-vault.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:8054",
            "caName": "ca.forensic.evidence-vault.com",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": ["-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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\nuV1vWo+zP/g8cWor7fEI8rPjz4SLw/3Rpw==\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"]
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}

the core.yaml which is ued is the default one provided in the documentation, i basically edit it using environmental variables through docker compose.
compose file containing configuartion for all the peers
Click to go to the file
Configtx.yaml file
Click to go the file
I am using 2.5.6 binaries as well as 2.5.6 images.

For Hyperledger Fabric v2.4 and later (including v2.5), you should be using the newer Fabric Gateway client API. The legacy SDKs (aimed at Fabric v2.2 and earlier) are no longer supported or actively maintained. Having said that, the legacy SDKs should continue to work OK.
Your error message suggests the client identity you are using does not have permission to access the channel. You need to ensure correct credentials are configured when connecting the Gateway.
Disabling service discovery in the legacy client means that it needs to have sufficient nodes (peers and orderers) defined in its local connection profile to be able to successfully transact with the Fabric network. This includes sufficient peers to meet endorsement requirements, and orderers to which endorsed transactions are submitted. Normally this information is obtained by the client from any network peer using service discovery. Using the newer Fabric Gateway client API, this is unnecessary since the client only needs to interact with a single network peer.

Hi, thank you for answering, about the newer fabric gateway client, i checked out the quickstart guide here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-gateway/blob/main/node/README.md
and in the compatibilty section it mentioned
This API requires Fabric v2.4 (or later) with a Gateway enabled Peer.
how can i enable gateway on peer, is it to be done through core.yaml or someway else

All Fabric v2.4 and later peers have the Gateway service enabled by default. The configuration is in the peer's core.yaml: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/3d796bccbc542ba1de0e4c77b6d3ae27cbd526af/sampleconfig/core.yaml#L49-L61

I adjusted the tlsCAcerts, guess i was using them incorrectly, and I got a new error :)
the gateway is attempting to make connection with the peer but it is failing.
peer logs -->
2024-04-26 13:05:29.750 UTC 003d ERRO [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> Server TLS handshake failed in 2.813503ms with error EOF server=PeerServer remoteaddress=172.22.0.1:50434
